# Remove all lines between two strings

Tags: string, sed, awk

In a sh shell script.

Given data in a text file:

```
string1  
string2 gibberish  
gibberish  
string3 gibberish  
string4
```

How could you use awk or sed to remove all lines between `string2` (inclusive) and `string3` (not including `string3`)?

to end up with:

```
string1  
string3  
string4
```

Comment: Heh, if you're chopping out _both_ string2 and string3 and everything in between, it's easy in sed: `/string2/,/string3/d`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this. Anything before "string2" will not be deleted.

```
awk 'BEGIN{f=0}
{
    match($0,"string2")
    if(RSTART){
        print substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
        f=1
        next
    }
    match($0,"string3")
    if(RSTART){
        $0=substr($0,RSTART)
        f=0
    }
}
f==0{print}
' file
```

output

```
$ cat file
string1 blah blah
text before string2 junk
gibberish
gibberis string3 text here
string4

$ ./shell.sh
string1 blah blah
text before
string3 text here
string4
```

Comment: This is a comprehensive solution that works in my case.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Are string1, string2,string3, etc. each on different lines? 
In that case, you can use awk:

```
awk '/string2/{flag=1} /string3/{flag=0} !flag'
```

or sed:

```
sed '/string3/p; /string2/,/string3/d'
```

Comment: That is thoroughly rad. Sed & awk syntax never sticks with me so every time I see such things I liken it to magic.

Comment: Those strings are on different lines.  There's another word after each string that is dynamic.

Comment: These totally worked if they were on lines by themselves.  But, I realized soon after you asked that there was some words before or after the string that didn't need to be erased that were on the same line.

Comment: Won't the above sed solution cause a doubling of a "string3" line is NOT preceded by a "string2" line?

Comment: You are right, but given the question of the OP, I made the assumption that input file always contains a line containing "string2" before the one containing "string3"

Comment: First approach with the awk worked for me pretty well, thx alot

Answer (score 1):

The following will work in *sed*

```
sed  '
/string2/,/string3/bdeleting
b
:deleting
s/string3.*/string3/
/string3/b
d
'
```

presuming we are matching up to the first occurrence of *string3* after *string2*

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample regex substitution:

```
s/string2.*?(?=string3)//sg
```

Which will remove everything from `string2` up to but not including `string3`.

Comment: I presume that's Perl, right? Cuz it doesn't look like either "awk or sed" (as the question states) to me. :-P

Comment: Yeah, and sed doesn't do non-greedy either.